# AWS Cognito - Logging end user activities for auditing

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-lambda, amazon-cognito

I am using Cognito for authentication. I am using the default sign-in page application for the end user to login to the application.

I need to log end-user activities related to the sign-in page for auditing purpose. Basically, I need to log when the user signed-up, signed-in, signed out and changed password. I can use triggers "Post Authentication Lambda Trigger" but forgot password and sign out events are missing. Could you please help me on how to achieve this?

Comment: I am afraid you will have to create a proxy which will execute your business logic regarding `password changed` only. Auditing sign up requests can be achieved with the `PreSignUp` event and for signing in events you already have it sorted out. If you are using Node.js for example, your proxy can invoke the `changePassword` API manually and audit whatever you'd like. Please refer to the API here: https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSJavaScriptSDK/latest/AWS/CognitoIdentityServiceProvider.html#changePassword-property

Comment: Signing out events should be easier since in order to sign a user out, all you need to do is remove the data from the local storage in the Browser, so you could trigger an API call to your "proxy" Lambda which would then audit that the logged in user has now logged out.

Comment: @ThalesMinussi, Thanks for your response.  AWS Cognito Advanced Security Features provides these features. We don't need to explicitly handle it for auditing.

Comment: @Manikandan Can you expand on this? The Advanced Security shows last 100 events per user, but are you able to capture them outside of this? I.e., use this somehow to view "how many users logged in on this date?"

Answer (score 9):

AWS Cognito Advanced Security Features provides this functionality[image]. You can find more details here https://aws.amazon.com/blogs/security/how-to-use-new-advanced-security-features-for-amazon-cognito-user-pools/

[Advanced Security Features](https://i.stack.imgur.com/21DhP.png)

Comment: Does this log sign out event?

Comment: Sign Out is not part of default aws sign in web app. Sing out is not logged here.

Comment: Can you please elaborate? what do you mean Sign out is not part of sign in web app, any useful links to understand better?

Comment: Has anyone discovered a way to view the individual Advanced Security events in CloudWatch Logs? The advanced security features with logging of each event -- date, event (e.g. Sign In), Result, Risk level, Risk decision, Challenge (e.g. Password:Failure), IP, Device, Location, Event feedback -- appear only within Cognito and only by user.

Comment: I'm aware of the CLI command cognito-idp [admin-list-user-auth-events](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/cli/latest/reference/cognito-idp/admin-list-user-auth-events.html), but like the Cognito GUI this only returns per user. Seems hack to (every 5 min) list all users, get auth events by user and write to CloudWatch Logs.

Comment: @rmharrison is scheduling the lambda to sync Cognito data with CloudWatch every 5mins the only way? It is hacky

Comment: It doesn't work. I can not find any logs even when Advanced Security features enabled. The blog post by the link is outdated and I have no "Users and groups tab" anywhere in the user pool to see "event histories for users". I'm surprised that this basic functionality is so difficult to get. The answer should provide more details of how to get the intended result, not just RTFM link.